# Flutter: how to keep the app running on background

Tags: android, flutter, dart, foreground-service

I'm using flutter dart for developed the for foreground app to keep the app running in background on Android. It's working fine until phone is on lock screen the app is show the notification is still running but the function won't work.
Is there any solution for this issues? Thanks

Comment: Have you setup Isolates ? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html

Comment: Can you give me an example how to set up Isolate Class. Sorry I'm new to flutter

Comment: you can try with work manager

Comment: You can try the package flutter_isolate, there is an example of how to use it there https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate. It is basically creating Isolate under the hood.

Comment: @harlandgomez will try it out. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can listen to App changes with `WidgetBindingsObserver` 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html

A good article for this (especially lockscreen) can be found here:
https://medium.com/@tomalabasteruk/flutter-in-app-lock-screens-f6a17fa02af

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  AppLifecycleState _notification; 
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    setState(() {
      _notification = state;
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    ...
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [flutter_background](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background) this worked for me